# Django, get value of the ChoiceField form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form which contain a choicefield of items on my database. 
My question is How can I get the selected value of my choicheField?

forms.py

```
class list_data(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, author, *args, **kwargs):
        super(list_data, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['List'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[(o.id, str(o)) for o in List.objects.filter(author=author)]
        )
```

views.py

```
def sms(request):
    form2  = list_data(author=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form2 = list_data(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            choice = form2.cleaned_data["List"]
            print(choice)

    else:
        return render(request, "data_list/sms.html", {"form2": form2})


    return render(request, "data_list/sms.html", {"form2": form2})
```

When I try to press the submit button it give me this error:

```
 int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'
```

So I changed the `form2 = list_data(request.POST)` for `form2 = list_data(author=request.user)`
the error is gone but it print nothing else.

Thanks for helping

models.py

```
class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    site = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=THE_SITE)
    content_list = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a POST request, you pass `request.POST` as first parameter, and thus as `author`, and not as data. You can rewrite the view to:

```
def sms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = list_data(request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            choice = form2.cleaned_data["List"]
            print(choice)
    else:
        form2  = list_data(author=request.user)
    return render(request, "data_list/sms.html", {"form2": form2})
```

I would however advise to use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) here that will remove some boilerplate logic, and then you can work with model objects:

```
class ListDataForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    list = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=List.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, author, *args, **kwargs):
        super(list_data, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['list'].queryset = List.objects.filter(author=author)
```

Note that according to the [**PEP-0008** style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the classes should be written in PerlCase (so `ListDataForm`, not `list_data`), and the attributes should be written in snake_case, so `list`, not `List`.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! I tried what you said, but when when I press the button it give me an number like: 73 or 114, instead of the name that in the choice field

Comment: @tiberhockey: yes, that makes perfect sense, since the `ChoiceField` will return the first item of the 2-tuple (the key), not the representation. What if you use a `ModelChoiceField`?

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem Ok thanks you, ill check it out with ModelForm tomorow